# Can you make `su` require a password, even if called with sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

So, I recently secured my root log-in and all `sudo` requests with 2-factor authentication. However, I noticed that if a user with `sudo` access that does **NOT** have 2FA enabled could easily `sudo su` and gain complete root access. Basically, I want to make sure that this can't happen, and it will still ask for the root password if you try to `su root` or `sudo su`.

Comment: Adding `sudo` to the command will execute 'su' as super user, if no other user is specified to the sudo command - super user has god powers and can do anything in the system - I don't think you can achieve this.

Comment: Darn. I guess not everything is possible :P

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: You seem to think running commands with `sudo` is not "complete root access". Unless you restricted which commands can be run with `sudo`, it definitely is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
Defaults rootpw
```

to your sudoers file. This will have "sudo" ask for a "root" password and not the "current user" password. You can use a "group" to restrict this to that group.

[Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/sudoers.5.html). The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo) is very solid.

---

Always use `visudo` to edit your sudoers file (it will validate changes).

Comment: This is probably not what OP wants, as it will ask for the root password every time, not just when running `su`.

Comment: Actually, that's perfect :D. My intention was to further secure [this](https://www.brownvpn.tk). If anyone managed to get themselves into the sudo group, this will help stop them.

Comment: It does. Using a good password and changing the password every so often helps too.

Comment: This even makes `sudo` requests call for the 2FA verification code for root. Even if they were clever enough to figure out the root password now, they're stopped for sure.